# iPhone, Xcode 6, UICollectionView iOS 5

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, ios5.1, missing-symbols

We have an app that needs to support iOS 5.1.  The app has been built using UIColletionView that is not supported in 5.1.  We don't need to use the code that uses UICollectionView on iOS 5.  When ignoring the XIB errors for the UICollectionView while targeting 5.1 iOS., the application compiles, but when trying to run on an iOS 5.1 device we get....

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UICollectionViewCell
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/BEC7B930-CA1B-467B-BB9D-75880BF0FCD1/
```

Which makes sense, but this is before the app even get's going (AppDelegate, etc).

Is there a way to have the app ignore the symbol problems and run and then we can "ignore" the UICollection view stuff in the code at runtime.